# I get this error when using a while loop to make a "list" IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

```
def main():

    endProgram = "no"

    #at the end the program will ask the user if the want to stop
    #if the say yes the program will end if they say no the will
    #cause the program to rerun
    while endProgram == "no":
        notGreenCost = [11]
        goneGreenCost = [11]
        savings = [11]
        months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

        #function calls
        notGreenCosts[12] = getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months)
        getGoneGreen(goneGreenCost, months)
        energySaved(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings)
        displayInfo(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings, months)

        endProgram = str(input("Do you want to end the program? yes or no"))

        def getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months):
            counter = 0
            while counter < 11:
                print("Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for", months[counter])
                notGreenCost[index] = int(input(":"))
                counter =  counter + 1


    return notGreenCost


main()
```

Every time I run it gives an index error after repeating the while statement in the first function once.

```
Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for January

:2

Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for February

:3
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/jackdennison/Documents/9.5.py", line 32, in <module> main()

  File "/Users/jackdennison/Documents/9.5.py", line 15, in main
    notGreenCosts[12] = getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months)

  File "/Users/jackdennison/Documents/9.5.py", line 26, in getNotGreen
    notGreenCost[counter] = int(input(":"))

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: An assignment statement such as notGreenCost = [11] creates a list consisting of one (1) item only which can be referenced as notGreenCost[0]. This is to say that you can either assign something to this address place, or obtain the value already assigned to this place. However, any attempt to reference a place like notGreenCost[k] where k is not zero will fail. months, for instance, has 12 places because you have assigned twelve items to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill Bell indicated you are trying to define size of array using

```
notGreenCost = [11]
goneGreenCost = [11]
savings = [11]
```

One of correct way of doing that would be as follows that would create empty list that can hold 12 elements.

```
notGreenCost = [None] * 12
goneGreenCost = [None] * 12
savings = [None] * 12
```

I hashed out following function for which there was no info.

```
#getGoneGreen(goneGreenCost, months)
#energySaved(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings)
#displayInfo(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings, months)
```

And made basic loop and data input working for you to give basic idea.

**Working Code**

```
import sys

def main():
def getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months):
        counter = 0
        while counter < 12:
            print("Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for", months[counter])
            notGreenCost[counter] = int(input(":"))
            counter =  counter + 1
        return notGreenCost

endProgram = "no"

#at the end the program will ask the user if the want to stop
#if the say yes the program will end if they say no the will
#cause the program to rerun
while endProgram == "no":
    notGreenCost = [None] * 12
    goneGreenCost = [None] * 12
    savings = [None] * 12
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    #function calls
    notGreenCosts = []
    notGreenCosts = getNotGreen(notGreenCost, months)
    #getGoneGreen(goneGreenCost, months)
    #energySaved(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings)
    #displayInfo(notGreenCost, goneGreenCost, savings, months)
    endProgram = str(raw_input("Do you want to end the program? yes or no:"))
    if endProgram == 'yes':
        print "notGreenCosts=",notGreenCosts
        sys.exit()
    else:
        main()
```

main()

**Output / Display**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'January')
:11
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'February')
:12
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'March')
:13
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'April')
:14
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'May')
:15
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'June')
:16
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'July')
:17
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'August')
:18
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'September')
:19
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'October')
:20
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'November')
:21
('Enter GONE GREEN energy costs for', 'December')
:22
Do you want to end the program? yes or no:yes
notGreenCosts= [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
>>>
```

**NOTE :**  Upon choosing `no` as menu option after entering `december` , I put `main()` function to rerun to demonstrate looping capability. You can change it as per your need.

Hope this helps.